# Mousemove Event: mouse position relative to parent element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a div that I want to listen to the `mousemove` event to see the offset between the mouse and the top of the div (so I use event.layerY). Inside this div I have another div.

The problem is when I move my mouse over this inner div, my `mousemove` event listens to the inner div and not the outer div where I set the listener to. Meaning `event.layerY` will give me the offset to the inner div and not the outer div.

This is my code:

```
this.draglistener = this.renderer.listen(this.container.nativeElement, 'mousemove', e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

As you can see I tired `stopPropagation()`but that doesn't work.
I also tried this:

```
if (e.target !== this.container.nativeElement) {
            return;
}
```

But this way it just stops listening to the event when moving over the inner div. So thats not working too.

Also I can't do `pointer-events: none;` for the inner div because I need to listen to some other events on this div.

Any Ideas?

Comment: did you try `e.preventDefault()` with `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: It appears to work with standard event binding, without stopping propagation. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfkxte).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for the code. I found out why its not working for me. I have the inner div set to `position: absolute` (CSS). When you change it, your code will behave like mine. But I need the position to be relative. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the mouse position relative to the outer `div`, subtract the client position of the outer `div` from the client position of the mouse. A template reference variable `outerDiv` can be used to pass the outer element to the event handler.

```
<div #outerDiv (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event, outerDiv)">
  <div class="innerDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the event handler, the client mouse position is obtained with `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`, and the outer `div` client position is obtained with `outerDiv.getBoundingClientRect()`.

```
onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent, outerDiv: HTMLElement) {
  const bounds = outerDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  const posX = event.clientX - bounds.left;
  const posY = event.clientY - bounds.top;
  console.log(posX, posY);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfkxte) for a demo.

Comment: I had a situation where I couldn't control the scroll position on load, So I had to look at `window.scrollY` and subtract it from the top `let top = e.pageY - overlay_offset.top - scrollY_offset;`